# Can't set instance of class to anything, it's always null(Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

no matter what I do, it's always null

I have a class called DUEL and an instance of it called d, in an instance of a class called opponent(opponent.cs)

`DUEL d;`

When I create a new opponent with a prefab that has the opponent script on it, in the DUEL script I tried

```
GameObject foe = Instantiate(prefab);
enemy = foe.GetComponent<opponent>();
enemy.d = this;
```

But it doesn't work

So I tried in the opponent script in its Start function:

```
void Start()
{
d = FindObjectOfType<DUEL>();
}
```

and even put it in GetKeyDown to do it manually but nothing

The gameobject with DUEL on it is enabled, the DUEL script is enabled, I restarted Unity, I'm not sure what to do

How can I set the instance of the class without using the Inspector? I can use the Inspector just fine and it works but I obviously cannot do that because I'm instantiating a prefab into the world

Comment: Seems like your `prefab` variable is `null`.

Comment: `But it doesn't work` ... if it is indeed only `DUEL d;` it is implicitly `private` .. if you really wanted to assign this using `enemy.d = this;` it would need to be `public`

Comment: It wold really help to get a more complete [mcve]

Comment: @derHugo sorry, but no, I left out that it was public. I do admit that was my fault. DUEL d is indeed public. Sorry, I thought I provided enough code. I'm not sure what else to make it reproducible. You just have to have two scripts, instantiate a prefab containing the second script from the first script

Have a public FirstScript fs; in the second script, then assign fs from the first script after instantiating by going newObject.GetComponent<SecondScript>().fs = this;

Comment: @Morion it's not null

Comment: @JMAS well usually that woks just fine and on my side here does ... if everything is correct .. so obviously it isn't on your side ;) That's why I said please share your actual code because with the very little you provide it is not possible to reproduce this issue

Comment: @derHugo it seems I have realized the error of my situation, there were two DUEL d's, one in INHERIT and one in opponent. Thank you, wouldn't have realized it if I hadn't shared all my necessary code

Comment: But here's the code anyways, since if I had never shared it I would have never found the solution
INHERIT.cs: https://pastebin.com/4G3GeLCW
NPC: https://pastebin.com/zCbS8D4P
opponent: https://pastebin.com/MKR51LP9
DUEL: https://pastebin.com/DpFn5J97

Comment: @JMAS I don't see any in the `oponnent` script (but maybe it is because you already fixed it ^^) - but hey, glad you figured it out!